# want to add a jenkins slave as a different user say "UserX"

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have logged-in to Jenkins UI using my Unix credentials (pmandal).
Then I have added a slave node (Slave1).
Now when i "Launch slave", it tries to ssh from the MASTER to the Slave(Slave1) as "jenkins" USER, and ssh fails.
My requirement is: I want the ssh from the MASTER to the Slave as a different user say "UserZ", coz i want all my operations to be performed as UserZ.
But i am unable to do so.

So my main question here is : "How to i make the MASTER to ssh to the Slave as UserZ"?
Any help would be appreciated.jenk

Answer (score 0):

- create the credentials in jenkins store.
  This can be done from https://<yourjenkins.url>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/newCredentials
- connect the node with the option "launch agent agents via ssh jenkins". From the config page of the node, you can select the credentials you just created

Note: the option "launch agent agents via ssh jenkins" is the recommended way to connect unix/linux machines: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003929412-How-to-create-an-agent-in-Linux-from-console

Comment: but i want the Launch method to be "Launch agent via execution of command on the master". Thats what the requirement is.   Is there a way i can start jenkins as the "UserZ" and not as "jenkins" user?

Comment: [Note that before 2.176.1 the “Launch agent by connecting it to the master” used to be known as “Launch agent via Java Web Start”](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029791092-Why-is-the-option-Launch-agent-by-connecting-it-to-the-master-not-available?mobile_site=true&page=19)

Comment: I haven't used jnlp (java web start) in years. But if you continue on this way, I could advise trying to run the jnlp client as UserZ. If this doesn't work, you may try to "su UserZ"  from your pipeline but it's not a good practice. You could also list the command line options of the jnlp agent to see what params are available... But honestly I would just use the ssh agent plugin

Comment: Agree. Launch all Linux agents via SSH [SSH Build Agents](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-slaves/) and WIN agents as Windows service (DCOM) via [WMI Windows Agents](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-slaves/). And rather than running master, set up an agent on same host as master (under another id), is a safer practice.